# Why can't I download files using express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, deployment

I am learning web development using node.js and express.js. I know how to make a simple server and response to routes in express. I am trying to serve an `index.html` file using `res.sendFile`. The app serves `index.html` on route `"/"`. In the `index.html` file there is a paragraph tag containing a anchor tag. The `"href"` attribute of anchor tag is set to `href="localhost:port/req"`. I reply to route `"/req"` using `"res.download()"` trying to download `greeting.txt`.

When going to `localhost:port/req` the `greeting.txt` is downloaded but on clicking on anchor tag link doesn't download the file (greeeting.txt). I tried two options specified below.

1. `res.download("./greeting.txt");`
2. `res.download(__dirname + "/greeting.txt");`

But neither works. I want to download the `greeting.txt` by clicking on the link.
My question is what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Below are the files.

// server.txt

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
port = 2020;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/req", (req, res) => {
  // option 1
  res.download("./greeting.txt");
  // option 2
  res.download(__dirname + "/greeting.txt");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port: ${port}. Press Ctrl-C to terminate.`);
});
```

// index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="font-size: 40px; color: blue; text-align: center">
      Welcome to my Simple Site
    </h1>
    <p style="text-align: center">
      Click on the link to download
      <a href="localhost:2020/req">greeting.txt</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

// greeting.txt

```
Have a great day!
```

I was expecting the `greeting.txt` file to be downloaded on clicking the link.

I tried:

1. `res.download("./greeting.txt");`
2. `res.download(__dirname + "/greeting.txt");`

Comment: `res.download` is available in Expres `4.x`. Make sure you have the correct version. Also, the greeting.txt should be in the same directory as the server.js

Comment: Where does the link lead you? I think the problem is in the html `<a href="localhost:2020/req"` should be `href="http://localhost:2020/req"` or `href="/req"` for example.

Comment: @Md.MinhazAhamed Yes I have version ^4.18.2

Comment: @RolandStarke The link leads me nowhere. Btw I checked the code it is href and not src in my code. I will correct the code in my question.

Comment: Uh! silly me. You are not giving any http:// or https://.

For your case, use `http://localhost:2020/req` in the index.html

Comment: @RolandStarke Yes on fixing '<a href="localhost:2020/req"' to 'href="http://localhost:2020/req' it works. Thank You. `href="/req"` also works.